# .map() doing nothing and casting no error - react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am programming in Reactjs, es6/2015.
So I am trying to .map() over an array, (like I have done sooo many times before). When I print the Array to the console, I get all the correct information, but nothing happens. I can't render the component I want or a simple h1. There is no error in the console or in my web-pack watch. I simply have no clue what's going wrong, the code matches some other code I have written almost down to letter, and the other works. The only real difference between the two is different var names.
My code:

```
show = [{content}, {content}, {content}];

render () {
 return <div className="box">
  {show.map( (item, key) => {
    <MyComponent item={item} key={key} 
                 choice={this.choice.bind(this)} />
  })}
 </div>;
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in es2015 arrow function syntax, if you are not specifying the function body as a one-liner, then you need to use curly braces to define the function body and use a return statement to return a value from the function body. Here in your mapper function you have the curlies, but no return statement.

Comment: @harun Please don't describe it in terms of lines (e.g. "one-liner") -- what matters is whether or not it's an expression. More in [my post here](http://thehighcastle.com/blog/138/es2015-arrow-functions-implicit-return).

Comment: @JMM thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @harun np. I think avoiding that phrasing will help people that don't fully understand it not get confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have return inside the map function, otherwise you just have an empty array.

Your component should be:

```
render () {
 return <div className="box">
  {show.map( (item, key) => {
    return <MyComponent item={item} key={key} choice=this.choice.bind(this)} />
  })}
 </div>;
 }
```

Parenthesis are not needed for the return values as far as I know (I never use them and have never encountered any issue).

Comment: Thank you! A bit embarrassed I didn't notice that, so glad you helped!